# SVM algortihm use shape to differentiate succesfull predictions and errors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, svm

It´s my first post so apologies i´m im skipping procedures. I´ve tried to look for a similar answer but didnt found it.

I have to differentiate succesfull predictions from a svm algorithm from errors using shape (like dots for succesfull prediction and triangles for errors)

```
>f21<-ggplot(testData, aes(x=Km, y=Margen, color=Comercial)) + geom_point(aes(size=Ingresos)) + >geom_smooth(method=lm, aes(fill=Comercial))+ stat_ellipse(type = "norm")
```

[f21 plot][1]

I am supposed to use a trained model_svm to use this. The code I´ve used for svm algorithm its:

RNGversion('3.5.3')

```
set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(Data_PEC), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3))
trainData <- Data_PEC[ind==1,]
testData <- Data_PEC[ind==2,]
model_svm = svm(trainData[,1:4], trainData$Comercial)
preds_svm = predict(model_svm, testData[,1:4])
table(preds_svm, testData$Comercial)
```

preds_svm  A  B  C
        A 10  0  0
        B  0 12  2
        C  0  0 14

I see there´s two missclassifications, but I have no idea how to use this to change the shape in the plot.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It seems that the plot/figure you wanted to post isn't attached. Would you please re-uplaod it?

Comment: Add a shape aesthetic with a variable that shows whether the prediction is correct. Something like `shape=preds_svm==Comercial`.

Comment: shape=preds_svm==Comercial Actually works thanks!! I thought it was going to add a shape for each cathegory, but it works like TRUE FALSE